# TPS2553 Current limiting

Tags: led, current-limiting

Editing this so it can be deleted for double post reasons.

I'm building a keyboard which will use SK6803 mini-e LEDs (ws2812 driver). I'm using a Pi Pico and as such the USB limit for current draw is ~500mA. I'm looking to limit the current draw from the LEDs to around 300-400mA and I found out that the [TPS2553DBVR IC](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS2553/part-details/TPS2553DBVR) can do this, however I'm a bit confused about the NFAULT and EN pins.

In my current design I don't have enough GPIO pins on my MCU for the EN and NFAULT signals so I was wondering if I can ignore the NFAULT, either leaving it floating or pulling it high (or low, I'm not sure tbh), and for the EN pin either just having 5V+ going in or using the same data signal which turns on the LEDs (also a 5V signal, but driven) so that the current limiter is always on? I just want it to consistently limit the current in the given range.

My schematic so far is looking like this:
[image]

Comment: (I'm closing this question to allow it to be merged with the accidental duplicate question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/689991/tps2553-current-limiting-for-rgb-leds )